# Getting a MySQL syntax error when using @dummy as part of the SQL statement string

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to run the following statement in Java and I'm getting a MySQL syntax error when executing @dummy as part of the code.  I'm using @dummy as part of the SQL statement to skip certain unwanted columns from being imported from the csv file.  When I execute the SQL statement inside MySQL the same statement works just fine but is failed at the @ symbol in Java.  Here is a sample of the code I'm trying to run...

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    java.sql.Connection connection = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("Connecting database...");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.println("Database connected!");
        java.sql.Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();


        int rss = stmt.executeUpdate(
                  "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/downloads/test.csv' INTO TABLE test"
                + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
                + "ENCLOSED BY '\"'"
                + "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"
                + "IGNORE 1 LINES"
                + "(Id,Title,@dummy,Issue,Project)"
                + "SET Project = ('Test');"
                );

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Closing the connection.");


        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    }
```

I'm not sure if the Java compiler is seeing the "@" as an annotation or something else entirely but I've been unable to find any information on this issue.

Here is the error message I get...

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TERMINATED BY ','ENCLOSED BY '"'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1
>   LINES(Id,Title,' at line 1

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't you need to add spaces? At the moment, I think it's concatenation your SQL as `INTO TABLE testFIELDS` - try adding a space at the end of each line of SQL?

Comment: You're missing white spaces in the query. For example, it contains `INTO TABLE testFIELDS`.